# How do I change an HTML element with incrementing values?

Tags: javascript, html

When I go on the page, I have 0 cookies to start with. I made an if statement saying if there are less than 10 cookies, hide the upgrade button. I'm clicking and incrementing the value by 1. Once I reach 10 cookies, how do I get the upgrade button to show? Would it be with an event listener or what?

```
var cookies = 0;
var cookieClick = 1;

function getCookie() {
    cookies += cookieClick;
    document.getElementById('cookieCount').innerHTML = cookies;
    document.getElementById('img').style.visibility = 'visible';
}

if (cookies < 10) {
    document.getElementById('up').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

function upgrade() {
    cookieClick *= 2;
    document.getElementById('up').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    alert('You have x2 the clicks!')
}
```

Comment: Right after `cookies += cookieClick;`, check the value against `10` and display the button. (I assume you already have `getCookie` set up as event listener for a cookie click).

Comment: it will much better to show your HTML code, so that we know how you are triggering the code, you need to check the value to 10

Answer (score 1):

Your `if (cookies < 10) {` isn't part of any function, so it'll only run once on page load. You probably want to include it in your getCookie() function instead, with an `else` to show the upgrade button when needed.

```
function getCookie() {
    cookies += cookieClick;
    document.getElementById('cookieCount').innerHTML = cookies;
    document.getElementById('img').style.visibility = 'visible';
    if (cookies < 10) {
        document.getElementById('up').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('up').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
}
```

(But if the cookie value never decreases, you could simplify this a bit by just loading the page with the element hidden initially and only check for `cookies > 10` to reveal it.)

Comment: Love this one. One problem though. Once I upgrade, I want that upgrade to disappear completely and add another upgrade button when I get to another milestone. When I upgrade, it disappears but comes back once I reach 10 again. I'm sorry I'm so new to javascript. I really only know the very basics. Surprised I'm even getting this far! Lol Would a loop fix it or no?

Comment: That's sort of a separate question, but: you want getCookie to not show the button if the upgrade has already happened.  The upgrade function multiplies cookieClick by two. So in getCookie, in the `else` clause that makes the button visible, you'd need to add another `if` statement that checks the value of cookieClick, and only makes the button visible if it's still 1.

Comment: Duh, that's so obvious. Thanks! But there's a problem with that. The upgrade button still shows until I press the cookie button.

if (cookieClick == 2) {
            document.getElementById('up').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }

This is the code I did and it works but it only gets hidden after I click to get more cookies.

Comment: I'm kind of losing track of which buttons you want visible when, but if you need one of the buttons hidden to begin with, just set its visibility to hidden in the CSS.   This is all really just a matter of thinking through the logic of how you want the program flow to go -- start with the initial state, think about what situations will change that state, and what information you need available at that time to control how the state changes.

Comment: It's pretty easy for beginning coders to get hung up on the syntax and language constructs and forget to just think through a plan... the planning is 90% of writing a program, though.  It's a good idea to sit down and write out an english-language or pseudocode version of your program first; that'll let you clarify the logic before you dive into the code itself, so you know what code you need to write.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. My problem is that this code:

if (cookieClick == 2) { document.getElementById('up').style.visibility = 'hidden'; }

only gets executed after I click the 'Cookie' button and not the 'Upgrade' button. I tried putting that line of code in the upgrade function but it didn't work.

What happens is when I upgrade once, I can upgrade infinitely until I click the button to get more cookies and THEN the button is hidden.

EDIT: I fixed it. Lmao. I put that line of code in the getCookie AND upgrade function and it worked. Hm... Seems redundant but it works.

Comment: I know I could make that line of code a function but it still seems redundant to put it in two different functions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an onClick event listener could check your current cookie count and toggle your upgrade button for visibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="incrementCount()"> b1 </button>
<button id="b2" style="visibility:hidden" onclick="something()">b2</button>

<script>
var cookies = 0;
var cookieClick = 0;

function incrementCount(){
  cookieClick = cookieClick + 1;
  console.log(cookieClick)
  if(cookieClick == 10){  
  document.getElementById('b2').style.visibility = "visible"
 }
}

function something(){
 alert('i work')
}
</script>
```

You can try this simple piece of code.